# How to build a 2D array from 1D array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

For this method I have to build a 2D array from a 1D char array using user inputs on which strings they want to use. For example:

```
const char *array_of_constant_strings[] ={"hi","some","random","strings"};
```

if the user input 123, I would want to return a 2D array containing

some

random

strings

Where the # of rows depends on the length of the user input (which was put into an array) and the length depends on the length of the string in the array. I was wondering how I would be able to do this on C. So far I have

```
int lengthofarray = sizeof(user_input) / sizeof(user_input[0]);
int returnArray[lengthofarray][maxStringLength];
for (int i= 0; i< lengthofarray, i++){
    for (int j=0; j <maxStringLength , j++){
        returnArray[i][j] = array_of_constant_strings[i];
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do right now is go through every char in the chosen string to add it to the 2D array. In java I would just be able to use the charAt function, but I don't think C has that. I know this is incorrect but I'm not sure how to place one string from a 1D array into a 2D array if that makes sense? Also, is there a simpler way to do this where I can update the pointers instead of trying to iterate over the strings?

Comment: Instead of doing a 2D array and access elements like `x[i][j]` do a 1D array and access like `x[i * n + j]` where `n` is the total number of rows.

Comment: @Havenard `n` is the total number of columns, not of rows (though in an square matrix they have equal value).

Comment: I must have misunderstood the issue; please disregard my answer for now... Can you explain; how come strings of different length constitute a square matrix?

Comment: @isrnick You're correct, a little brain fart there.

Comment: @ssd you understood the OPs issue correctly, the comment by Havenard would help to answer the title of the question, but not the actual issue posted in the rest of the question. So ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. handling user input and mapping the input to indexes of your constant array; and
2. storing the strings that correspond to the indexes (digits) entered by the user:

For handling your user input, you are better off taking the input as a string and then checking each characters is a digit (with `isdigit()` from `ctype.h`) and that it is in the range of the number of elements in your array of pointers. You cannot convert the input to `int` or input of `012` would discard the leading `0`.

Since you are working with array indexes, you can simply convert the digits to their numeric value by subtracting `'0'` for the ASCII value.

Another consideration is validating the input string before outputting or copying your strings to their final storage. Looping over the input performing validation in a separate loop before you loop outputting or copying the strings is probably your best bet. (at least if you are outputting the results) Otherwise, you may have partial output shown before an error is encountered. (e.g. in your example, the user enters `138`)

The mapping of digits to indexes is straight forward. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 64

int main (void) {
    
    const char *acs[] ={"hi","some","random","strings"};
    char buf[MAXC];
    int nelem = sizeof acs / sizeof *acs;
    
    fputs ("enter number with element indexes for strings: ", stdout);
    
    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* read input as a string */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* loop validating all digits are less than nelem */
    for (int i = 0; buf[i] && buf[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(buf[i]) || buf[i] - '0' >= nelem) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%d' out of range.\n", buf[i] - '0');
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    /* loop outputting strings that correspond to digits entered */
    for (int i = 0; buf[i]; i++)
        if (isdigit(buf[i]))
            puts (acs[buf[i] - '0']);
    
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/string_index_from_int
enter number with element indexes for strings: 012
hi
some
random
```

or

```
$ ./bin/string_index_from_int
enter number with element indexes for strings: 123
some
random
strings
```

or if an index out of range is entered:

```
$ ./bin/string_index_from_int
enter number with element indexes for strings: 124
error: '4' out of range.
```

How you handle storing each of the strings that correspond to one of the indexes entered can take one of several forms. In the simple case, you know the number of pointers you have and the length of the longest string -- you can simply declare a 2D array of chars with the number of rows corresponding to the number of pointers and the number of columns equal to the longest string `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character. This requires a fixed size 2D array with all size information known before compile time. Here all that is needed:

```
char strings[4][8];
```

In that case you can simply add `string.h` as an included header, `int n;` as a counter and do:

```
#include <string.h>
...
    char strings[4][8];
    int nelem = sizeof acs / sizeof *acs, n = 0;
    ...
    /* loop validating all digits are less than nelem */
    for (int i = 0; buf[i] && buf[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(buf[i]) || buf[i] - '0' >= nelem) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%d' out of range.\n", buf[i] - '0');
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (strings[n++], acs[buf[i] - '0']);   /* copy to array/increment */
    }
    
    /* loop outputting strings that correspond to digits entered */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            puts (strings[i]);
```

(**note:** you cannot declare an array local to a function and return a pointer to the array -- the array no longer exists after function return)

The other option is a 2D VLA (*Variable Length Array*), which doesn't require the size to be known before compiling -- but beginning with C++11, compiler support for VLAs is optional (though most should continue to support them). There, all that is needed is you loop over your strings to find the longest and declare the VLA. (same return limitation applies)

The final option is to dynamically allocate storage to hold strings copied from your array of pointers. While you can declare a single block of memory to hold strings of a fixed size (sized for the longest string +1), the generic approach is to allocate a block of pointers and then allocate a block for each string, copy the string to the allocated block and then assign the starting address for the allocated block to each you your allocated pointers in turn.

Here you simply include `stdlib.h` for `malloc` and then allocate `nelem` pointers and allocate for each string matching an index entered by the user. You **validate** every allocation and you `free()` all memory when it is no longer needed. For example you could do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
    char** strings;
    ...
    /* loop validating all digits are less than nelem */
    for (int i = 0; buf[i] && buf[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(buf[i]) || buf[i] - '0' >= nelem) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%d' out of range.\n", buf[i] - '0');
            return 1;
        }
        if (!(strings[n] = malloc (strlen (acs[buf[i] - '0']) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc-strings[n]");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (strings[n++], acs[buf[i] - '0']);   /* copy to array/increment */
    }
    
    /* loop outputting strings that correspond to digits entered */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        puts (strings[i]);
        free (strings[i]);      /* free allocated string */
    }
    free (strings);             /* free pointers */
```

(**note:** you CAN return a pointer to `strings` from a function)

The is one more option that relies on the fact that *String Literals* have a lifetime equal to that of your program. So long as you never attempt to modify the pointer, you can simply allocate pointers and assign the address for the string literal to each pointer rather than copying the string. This will result in each of the pointers holding the address of the non-mutable string literal. It is mentioned for completeness but not recommended.

The output for all methods is the same. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you must copy the strings to the return array it would be better to use the function `strcpy` from `<string.h>` to copy each string.

```
const char *array_of_constant_strings[] ={"hi","some","random","strings"};
```

```
int returnArray[lengthofarray][maxStringLength];
for (int i= 0; i< lengthofarray, i++){
    strcpy(returnArray[i], array_of_constant_strings[i]);
}
```